# Characteristic functions dense in simple functions in $L^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider $L^1(X,Y)$ where $X=Y=[0,1]$ and $ \langle f, g\rangle =\int fg $.  Is the set of characteristic functions $\{\chi_{A}  \}$   dense in the set of simple functions $\{ s\}$, in the sense there is a sequence $\{\chi_{A_n}\}$

$$\langle \chi_{A_n}, g\rangle \to \langle s, g\rangle$$

for any continuous $g\in L^{\infty}(X,Y)$?

I read this answers here (http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6119055) but I didn't fully understand. It seems the answer is yes? Hope anyone offer some further explanation.

Comment: I think I have given a construction, but please check it.

Answer (score 5):

This does seem to work. This seems to be the idea of the construction:

Start by fixing a subinterval $I \subset [0,1]$. Recursively cut $I$ into $n$ pieces and define a function which is $1$ on $m$ of the pieces and $0$ on the rest. The resulting sequence, which I'll call $f_{q,k}$ where $q=\frac{m}{n}$, converges in the sense you've described to $\frac{m}{n} \chi_I$, as $k \to \infty$. This is essentially the content of your link. Roughly speaking, a sequence of characteristic functions which are somehow both "uniformly" spread across $I$ and have integral $\frac{m}{n} |I|$ will converge to $\frac{m}{n} \chi_I$.

Now for arbitrary $\alpha \in [0,1]$, get a rational sequence $q_n \to \alpha$. Consider the sequences $f_{q_n,k}$ as before. Take the diagonal sequence: $f_{q_n,n}$ will converge as $n \to \infty$ to $\alpha \chi_I$. Call the sequence that we just extracted $g_{\alpha,I,n}$.

Now we handle $\alpha \chi_A$ for a general measurable $A$. The idea is another diagonalization argument. Take a sequence of finite unions of intervals that approximate $A$, say $\{ \{ I_{n,k} \}_{n=1}^{N_k} \}_{k=1}^\infty$. Then consider $\sum_{n=1}^{N_k} g_{\alpha,I_{n,k},m}$. Diagonalize again, by considering $\sum_{n=1}^{N_k} g_{\alpha,I_{n,k},k}$. Then we've approximated $\alpha \chi_A$. There may be some technical issues with overlaps here, but I think those go away if we go far enough out into the sequence. At any rate, call the resulting approximation $h_{\alpha,A,k}$.

Now we finally approximate $\sum_{m=1}^N \alpha_m \chi_{A_m}$ by $\sum_{m=1}^N h_{\alpha,A_m,k}$. Again there may be some technicality about overlapping, but it should go away for large $k$.

Comment: Well the OP stated the functions take values in $[0,1]$, but your answer is otherwise spot-on. +1

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks. I changed the number; all that matters is that it is neither zero nor one. :)

Comment: Hi, but the link shows that we can approximate 1/2 but a sequence   $\{\chi_{A_n}\}$?

Comment: @user91360 I see, you are asking about whether they are *weakly* dense. I think the answer is still no, but an example might be more difficult to construct.

Comment: Hi, I have some difficulty in understanding "recursively" and the last sentence of the first paragraph, so recursively means for constructing $k$? and you mean $ \langle f_{q,k}, g\rangle \to \langle \frac{m}{n}\chi_{I}, g\rangle$  for all continuous $g\in L^1$?  I see it is the case for $g=1$?I don't know how to show this formally, Could you help? In addition, could the main conclusion holds for all $g\in L^1$?

Comment: @user91360 In the first step you break into $n$ pieces, in the second step you break each of those $n$ pieces into $n$ pieces, etc. The last sentence of the first paragraph is just trying to give a vague intuitive explanation of what the construction does. If it doesn't help you then it doesn't really matter, the rigorous part is what matters.

Comment: Thanks. For $ \int f_{q,k} g  \to \int\frac{m}{n}\chi_{I} g $  for all continuous $g\in L^1$,  I try to show this formally but didn't find ways to do it, could you give some hint for this? In addition, could the main conclusion holds for all $g\in L^1(X,Y)$?

Comment: @user91360 Yes, the design was that $\langle f_{q,k},g \rangle \to \langle q \chi_I,g \rangle$ for continuous $g$ mapping $[0,1]$ to itself. The idea is more or less in your link, but the details are nontrivial. I am also not sure how to get around the continuity requirement.