# A multiple of a characteristic function is the weak limit of a sequence of characteristic functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, weak-convergence

Consider $f\in L^1(I,I)$ where $I=[0,1]$ and $ \langle f, g\rangle =\int fg $.    For any given   $\frac{m}{n}\chi_{A}$  where $\frac{m}{n}$  rational and $A$ an subinterval in $I$, how would I show that a sequence of characteristic functions $\{\chi_{A_n}\}$

$$\langle \chi_{A_n}, g\rangle \to \langle \frac{m}{n}\chi_{A}, g\rangle$$

for all continuous $g\in L^{\infty}(I,I)$?

Suppose first we divide the interval $A$ into $n$ parts with $m$ parts with values equal to $1$ and do this recursively. Then how could I continue?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the relation of $(A_n)_n$ and $A$? Do you want to find *some* sequence $(A_n)_n$ such that the claim holds or.....?

Comment: Hi, I think there is no relation between $(A_k)_k$ and $A$. To avoid confusion, it would be better to replace $A$ by  $E$. I think here a convergence sequence $\{\chi_{A_k}\}$ would have already been given by: the recursively dividing $E$ into $n$ parts and setting $m$ of them with value 1, for each $k$ ( The procedure is given here,http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6119055) But   I don't understand why such sequence converges in the above sense formally.

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257501/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $g$ is uniformly continuous; let $\omega$ be its modulus of continuity.

Divide the interval $A$ into $kn$ equal subinterval, where $k$ is large. Let's say the subintervals are $I_1,\dots,I_{kn}$. For $j=1,\dots, n$ define 
$$
B_j = \bigcup_{r=0}^{k-1} I_{j+rn}
$$
Simply put, $B_j$ is the union obtained by taking every $n$th interval starting with $I_j$. The key point is for $j,\ell\in \{1,\dots,n\}$
$$
\left|\int_{I_j+rn}g-\int_{I_\ell+rn}g\right| \le \frac{|A|}{kn}\omega(|A|/k)
$$
which follows from the uniform continuity of $g$. (The number $|A|/k$  bounds the offset between the two intervals of integration.) Sum over $r$ to get 
$$
\left|\int_{B_{j}}g-\int_{B_{\ell}}g\right| \le \frac{|A|}{n}\omega(|A|/k)
$$
Note that the right-hand side is small when $k$ is large. So, the integral over all sets $B_{j}$ are about the same. In particular, taking 
$$A_k=B_1\cup\dots\cup B_m$$
achieves the goal 
$$
\int_{A_k}g\to \frac{m}{n}\int_A g
$$